# Setting a master file for org export with several included files

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Say I have a master org-mode `main.org` file including two files as follows

```
#+INCLUDE: "./tmp1.org" :minlevel 1
#+INCLUDE: "./tmp2.org" :minlevel 1
```

Is it possible, from the editing `tmp1.org`, to tell the export engine to call `main.org`--as a master file--to run this export?

I'd like to achieve what already exists with LaTeX files in Auctex where we can tell this mode what's the master file for the compilation, even when editing a sub file.

Thank you.

Comment: No doubt that it is possible, but AFAIK not out of the box. It will need a small amount of programming.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any good documentation on the way org-export is designed? I'd like to try to program something where the name of the master org-mode file would be stored in, e.g., #+MASTERFILE: <filename>, so that org-export can use this file instead of the current file.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments because they pointed in the wrong direction. What you need to do is write a function that wraps the `org-export-as` function, so that you call it with a filename argument (`org-export-as` operates on the current buffer). Then you need to recognize the existence of a `#+MASTERFILE` keyword and call your function with the value of the keyword. For how to do that, I would search in the Org mode sources for how `#+INCLUDE` is handled and use it as a model.

Comment: I'll do that, thank you for the clues.